# Cocos2D CGRectIntersect not found?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have problem with my game in Cocos2D (v2.0). I get two issues (I commented them in code parts). Here's Bullet.m file :

```
-(BOOL)checkCollisions:(CGRect)r
{
BOOL x = NO;

if(CGRectIntersectsRect([theGame myRect:self.mySprite],r)) //FIRST ISSUE - Sending 'id' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect'); 
                                                           //SECOND ISSUE - Instance method'-myRect:' not found (return type defaults to 'id') 
{
    x=YES;
    [self reset];
}
return x;
}
```

And later in this file :

```
-(void)update
{
switch (self.whoFired)
{
    case 1:
        [self.mySprite setPosition:ccp(self.mySprite.position.x,self.mySprite.position.y + self.firingSpeed)];

        for(Enemy * s in theGame.enemies)
        {
            if(ccpDistance(self.mySprite.position, s.mySprite.position)<30)
            {
              if([self checkCollisions:[theGame myRect:s.mySprite]]) //FIRST ISSUE - Sending 'id' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect')
                                                                     //SECOND ISSUE - Instance method '-damage' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
                {
                    [s damage];
                }
            }
        }
        break;
...
```

So, two errors are the same : Passing 'id' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect').
Those other two are about Damage and MyRect functions. Of course they exists (in GameScene.m and in Enemy.m files; everything is connected by .h files, and I get no errors in Damae and MyRect functions):

```
-(CGRect)myRect:(CCSprite *)sp
{
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(sp.position.x-sp.textureRect.size.width/2, sp.position.y-sp.textureRect.size.height/2, sp.textureRect.size.width, sp.textureRect.size.height);
return rect;
}


-(void)damage
{
self.hp--;
[self.mySprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                          [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:0.5 red:255 green:0 blue:0],
                          [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:0.5 red:255 green:255 blue:255],nil]];
if(hp<=0)
{
    [self destroy];
}
}
```

What could be wrong? Why compiler can't see myRect and damage functions?

Comment: Is the prototype of `-myRect:` in the header file of the class it is declared in? and is that header imported into the Bullet class somewhere?

Comment: Header is imported. The prototype is not created, but I tried with it also, and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use default boundingBox of CCSprite ?

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect([self.mySprite boundingBox],r))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now. One more thing - I get a few warnings like "Object (Enemy, Bullet etc) may not respond to "update" ". Update function is implemented correctly, everything works excellent, but I get those warnings. How to get rid of them?

Comment: in interface also define same.